# i can't enter to control panel of my WordPress site

Tags: https

I changed http to https for my site from control panel > setting > general > url site & url wordpress.
Then I can't enter to my control panel of my site (/wp-admin) because it go to https://mysite/wp-admin

Comment: what does your browser say?

Comment: google chrome ..

Comment: Calm down please. What is your browser showing when you try to access `wp-admin`? Is is something like `Your connection is not private`?

Comment: if i go to http:// my browser say "Forbidden .. You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server." , and if i go to https:// my browser say "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" and say "can't safe connection"

Answer (score 0):

EASIEST METHOD:
Under the error on the page your getting click i understand the risks and continue on to your site.

NEXT EASIEST METHOD:
Add this to your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
```

(replace example with your url)

NEXT METHOD:
Go into your myphp admin open your database and go to the options table.  In there look for the entries for your site urls.  remove the http and you'll be good to go.

NEXT METHOD:
If you can't do that but have access to ftp you can upload verston 3.1 of the file on this page
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
 to your www (webroot) and the go to www.example.com/Search-Replace-DB-master  (replace example with your site).

It will load a page that will allow you to change your settings.
just replace https://www.example.com with http://www.example.com

REMEMBER TO DELETE THAT FOLDER AFTER YOU ARE DONE.  It's  A BIG SECURITY ISSUE TO LEAVE IT.

Comment: i do 1st method but a problem isn't solved, and i try 2nd method but i don't found http in database, i don't try 3rd method because i don't understand it ! 1st method is simple but maybe there any error

Comment: you should see a table with somethign like wp_options.  In that table you'll see 2 fields (site_url and home_url)  the values of both of them will be https://www.yoursite.com.  You need to remove the "s" from the http.